# Could you explain evaluation of 5--4 in Jupyterlab?

Tags: python, expression, jupyter-lab

I'm new to Python and Jupyter-lab. In Jupyter-lab, when I try to run expression:

5--4

It gives output as 9. Could you explain why?

[image]

Comment: This is basic math. 2 minus make a plus.

Comment: It's parsed as `(5)-(-4)`.

Comment: @Julien: my bad I assumed that Python expects a brace to evaluate a minus X minus, which would be like 5-(-4).

Answer (score 0):

Python parses the expression as (5)-(-4) and hence a 9 is returned.